# What is the least technical method to use D (dlang) with Qt5

Tags: qt5, d, gtk3

I am a beginner wanting to learn D. I would like to be able to create simple GUI applications with Qt5.

I have found tutorials for adapting Qt Designer .ui files to python scripts using PyQt5. Might there be a comparable method for using Qt5 with D?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried this myself, but you may start by having a look at the **QtE5** project [here](https://github.com/MGWL/QtE5).

Answer (score 1):

Gtk+'s Glade says it supports dlang.

I am going to look into this further.

I added a tag for Gtk3.

(Sorry, I know the question was for Qt. It looks for now that I have converted to Gtk.)